# An alternative to a PROC SUMMMARY approach when summing variables across multiple observations

Tags: sas

I am dealing with a repeated measures dataset in a wide format. Each observation represents one measurement for one subject and each subject is measures six times. The data contains mainly dummy variables.

I am looking to do a count of unique dummy variable values across all six observations for each subject.

Have:

```
 MeasurementNum    SubjectID    Dummy0    Dummy1    Dummy2    Dummy3   Dummy4         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
            1          1          1          1         0         0         0
            2          1          0          1         0         1         0
            3          1          -          -         -         -         -
            4          1          0          0         1         1         0
            5          1          -          -         -         -         -
            6          1          0          0         0         1         0
            1          2          1          0         0         1         0
            2          2          0          0         0         0         0  
            3          2          0          1         0         0         0
            4          2          1          1         0         1         0
            5          2          -          -         -         -         -  
            6          2          1          1         1         0         0
```

Want:

```
                                       Total for       Overall
 MeasurementNum    SubjectID    ...    MeasurementNUM  Total      
--------------------------------...-----------------------------  
            1          1        ...          2         4                  
            2          1        ...          2         4                  
            3          1        ...          -         4                  
            4          1        ...          2         4                 
            5          1        ...          -         4                
            6          1        ...          1         4                  
            1          2        ...          2         4                  
            2          2        ...          0         4                    
            3          2        ...          1         4                  
            4          2        ...          3         4                  
            5          2        ...          -         4                    
            6          2        ...          3         4
```

My current approach is to consolidate all six rows within each subject to one rows retaining value 1 using `Proc MEANS` with `BY` and `OUTPUT` statements, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101674/in-sas-how-to-consolidate-non-zero-values-in-rows-by-group) related question. I then use `Proc SUMMARY` to get the values listed under variable 'Total` in the have statement.

```
proc summary
data=have;
By SubjectID
class Dummy1-4;
output out=want sum=sum;
```

Is there a way to get the distinct/unique counts across observations without consolidating rows first?

I prefer `PROC SQL` as it will also allow me to do conditional counts according to subject covariates present in my working dataset. I.e. producing the want descriptives on condition of a covariate specific to the subject.

Comment: PROC SUMMARY and MEANS are really the same thing and most interchangeable. To help out, can you show the code that does work, and maybe simplify your data to be a [mcve] that we can work with, showing what you expect as output? I'm wondering if the MAX statistic isn't what you want instead.

Comment: I seem to not be able to edit questions at this point. I have posted a support request on the meta site. As soon as the problem is resolved, I will edit the question. For now i can say that for each `SubjectID` I would like to produce a descriptive telling me how many dummy variables had value 1 across all six measurements. For `ID1` this would be 1 (`Dummy1`). For `ID2` this would be 3 (`Dummy 0`, `Dummy1` and `Dummy99`).

Comment: Why would SQL make getting conditional counts any easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that using `PROC SUMMARY` (aka PROC MEANS) will be the easiest way.  Sounds like you want to find the MAX for each SUBJECT and then SUM those to get the subject totals.

```
proc summary data=have nway ;
  class SubjectID ;
  var Dummy0-Dummy999;
  output out=any(drop=_type_ _freq_) n=n_reps max= ;
run;

data want ;
  set any ;
  total = sum(of Dummy0-Dummy999) ;
run;
```

Not sure how SQL helps any with conditional counts. But you could generate the counts and total in one step with PROC SQL, but it would require wallpaper code like this:

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
    select SubjectID
         , count(*) as n_reps
         , max(dummy0) as dummy0
         , max(dummy1) as dummy1
         ...
         , max(dummy999) as dumyy999
         , sum
         ( max(dummy0) 
         , max(dummy1) 
         ...
         , max(dummy999)
         ) as Total
    from have
    group by 1
  ;
quit;
```

You could probably define a macro (or some other tool) to generate that wallpaper code for you from a list of variable names.